# How to achive this without using Sub Query, CTE and Prodedure

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with 2 fields

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_tab 
(
     id int identity primary key, 
     value float
);

INSERT INTO Temp_tab(value)
VALUES (65.09),(17.09);
```

I want to select all the records that are greater than Avg(Value).

Say... `Select * from temp_tab where value > (select avg(value) from temp_tab);`
This above query(using subquery) gives me the expected output

```
1   65.09
```

I want to achieve this without using Sub Query, CTE and Prodedure, since i am using Spark DB. Spark Db does not  support Sub Queries, CTE and Prodedures

Comment: Does spark allow `[not] EXISTS(correlated subquery)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite painfully with a `cross join` and aggregation:

```
Select t1.id, t1.value
from temp_tab t1 cross join
     temp_tab t2
group by t1.id, t1.value
having t1.value > avg(t2.value);
```

As a note:  Spark SQL claims to support subqueries (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive)).  So, your original query should work.  If it only supports subqueries in the `from` clause, then you can do:

```
Select t.*
from temp_tab t join
     (select avg(value) as avgvalue from temp_tab) a
     on t.value > a.avgvalue;
```

Comment: Add to `CROSS JOIN` solution that this won't return all records but only distinct [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98ec45/1/0). OP says "I want to select **all the records** that are greater than Avg(Value)."

Comment: @lad2025 . . . The `id` is a primary key, so the results will include all distinct rows that match the condition.

Comment: Ok, I saw your earlier answer without id

Comment: @lad2025 . . . I should have been clearer in the first version.  The `col1, . . ` was intended to mean all the columns in the table.  Belatedly, I realized there are only two, so that is easy to put directly into the query.

Comment: @MidhunSiva . . . Instead of `cross join`, you can use either a comma (which I abhor in the `from` clause unless necessary) or `join . . . where 1 = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

spark-sql accept this query under version of 1.6.x

```
select * from (select * from tenmin_history order by TS_TIME DESC limit 144) a order by TS_TIME
```

This query solved my problem.